# Azure Functions BlobTrigger not logging

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I'm trying to create an Azure function triggered with a BlobTrigger. When I'm adding new files to the target container, the function runs which I can see by looking at **Invocations** as showing with time when triggered and status "Success" in Monitor on Azure portal. However, there's nothing appearing in the **Logs** apart from the 'Connected!' welcome text.

Here's the boilerplate run.csx I've tried with and without a little modification:

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
///    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob");
}
```

and function.json (to which I've added an input binding with the same path):

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "path": "rsqd-ukraine-xl/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "blobTrigger"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "rsqd-ukraine-xl/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

I'm running this on App Service Plan B1.

What shall I do to see the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should make sure you have upload one or more files to 'rsqd-ukraine-xl' container.

Second, please notice that azure function log tab is fragile. So it is not show the logs every. If you want to have a look of the logs that the log tab in portal did not shown, you should go to this place:

```
https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
```

And then click in LogFiles -> Application -> Functions -> Function -> yourtriggername.

You will find the log files in it.

Comment: Thanks. You solution is working. I've also checked back on the portal console and it works as well. Might be they had a temporary issue that day.